# update button visibility in Activity from getview() of custom adapter

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

As the title says: I need to update button visibility in activity inside getview().

Comment: could you be more precise ? Is the button part of the view returned by getView() or not ?

Comment: if it's not part of the view returned by getView(): you can pass the buttonView into the custom adapter (through the constructor or a public setter method) and then easily use .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public method in activity.

```
setButtonVisibilty(boolean isVisible){
// set button visibility
}
```

Inside getView() method use

((YourActivityName) context).setButtonVisibilty(true/false);

Answer (score 1):

Use this at any place:

```
Button btn; // Your Button view
b.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
```

And In Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = convertView;
  if (v != null) {
     Button btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
     b.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```